# MATLAB create movie from 16 bit images

Tags: matlab, video, image-processing

I have a simple MATLAB sequence which is intended to create an AVI movie from a collection of uint16 images:

```
video = VideoWriter( vidName );
video.FrameRate = ( frmRate );
open( video );
for i=1:size
    img = imread( picNames(i).name );
    writeVideo( video, img );
end
close( video );
```

This produces the error `IMG must be one of the following classes: double, single, uint8`. Any ideas as to how I might get around this without loss of precision or adding compression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add the following line before `writeVideo( video, img );`:

```
img=im2double(img);
```

You will not lose precision.